# How to detect gap between cached feeds list and latest feeds list

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, greendao

I am struggling to show gap if exists in my feed view. Let me explain what I mean by gap.In my feed list view, I am getting 20 results at a time and save them into local cache (GeenDAO DB) and display in recylerview. Now the problem is when a user visits app after 1 day or long time then on open feed view he can see latest 20 results and after that cached old result seen but there may be many items exist after 20 items. So I don't know how to detect the start of missing item and show button to a user to call and fetch results after 20 items.

Should I check first item id of cached result list and last item id of the latest list and compare if both do not equal that means there is a gap and show "Show more feeds" button. is it a good approach?

Here is my code:

OnViewCreated() method: I am showing result from the cache:

```
List<LatestFeedsItem> latestFeedsItemList = LocalStorageUtil.getDetail(new LatestFeedsItem(), LatestFeedsItemDao.Properties.DateCreated);
    mAdapter = new LatestFeedsAdapter(mContext, (latestFeedsItemList != null && !latestFeedsItemList.isEmpty()) ? latestFeedsItemList : new ArrayList<>());
    setFeedItemClickListener(mAdapter);
    rvFeeds.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then immediately call server to fetch latest 20 results:

```
// Call to get latest feeds
    getLatestFeeds();
```

I am using pagination to load next 20 results on the scroll by:

```
rvFeeds.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;

            // mocking network delay for API call
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> getLatestFeeds(), 200);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCursorAvailable() {
            return curser != null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });
```

Now this is my getLatestFeeds() method:

```
 private void getLatestFeeds() {
    if (currentPage <= 1) {
        mAppController.getLatestFeeds(null, getLatestFeedsCallBack());
    } else {
        if (curser != null) {
            mAdapter.addLoadingFooter();
            mAppController.getLatestFeeds(curser, getLatestFeedsCallBack());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is getLatestFeedsCallBack() method:

```
 private ICallback<LatestFeedsResponse.LatestFeedsResult> getLatestFeedsCallBack() {
    return new ICallback<LatestFeedsResponse.LatestFeedsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void getResponse(LatestFeedsResponse.LatestFeedsResult latestFeedsResult) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAdapter.removeLoadingFooter();
            if(latestFeedsResult!=null&&latestFeedsResult.getMatches()!=null) {
                List<LatestFeedsItem> latestFeedsItems = latestFeedsResult.getMatches();
                if (latestFeedsItems != null && !latestFeedsItems.isEmpty()) {
                    // Store response in cache
                    for (LatestFeedsItem latestFeedsItem : latestFeedsItems) {
                        setCreatorUploader(latestFeedsItem);
                    }

                    List<LatestFeedsItem> list = LocalStorageUtil.getDetail(new LatestFeedsItem(), LatestFeedsItemDao.Properties.DateCreated);
                    if(list!=null&&!list.isEmpty()){
                        LatestFeedsItem item = list.get(0);
                        String dbNewestItemId = item.getId();
                        LatestFeedsItem item1 = latestFeedsItems.get(latestFeedsItems.size());
                        String newestOldestItemId = item1.getId();

                        if(!dbNewestItemId.equalsIgnoreCase(newestOldestItemId)){
                          //Add a null item to show button and onclick again call getLatestFeed() method with curser.
                        }
                    }


                    LocalStorageUtil.put(latestFeedsItems.toArray());
                    mAdapter.addAll(latestFeedsItems);

                    if (latestFeedsResult.getCurs() != null) {
                        Log.d(sTAG, "Curser :" + latestFeedsResult.getCurs());
                        curser = latestFeedsResult.getCurs();
                    } else {
                        curser = null;
                        isLastPage = true;
                        //end of page
                    }

                    Log.d(sTAG, "Number of data received: " + latestFeedsItems.size());
                } else {
                    curser = null;
                    isLastPage = true;
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else {
                curser = null;
                isLastPage = true;
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            isLoading = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
            mAdapter.removeLoadingFooter();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isLoading = false;
            String error = ParseNetworkErrors.parseVolleyError(volleyError);
            if (!error.isEmpty()) {
                if (error.equalsIgnoreCase(PlownsApplication.getInstance().mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("volley_entity_not_found_error"))) {
                    error = String.format(PlownsApplication.getInstance().mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("volley_entity_not_found_error"), "feed");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error != null ? error : "Oops! Some thing went wrong please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I know the question is too long but it is necessary to explain everything. 
Please suggest me something. Thanks

Comment: Or Should I search cached list's first item in the latest list and if not exits that mean there is a gap and add a "show more feed" button?